# How to force update angular's view from backend?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm writing a Tauri project using angular on frontend.
The problem is that I can't force updating angular's view from backend.
I have service which provides data to components and recieves signals from backend to update data.

```
export class MyService {
    public data: string[] = [];
    public serviceUpdated = new EventEmitter<void>();

    public constructor() {
        this.updateService();
        listen('data-updated', () => { this.updateService(); })
    }

    private updateService() {
        forkJoin({
            // ask backend to send new data 
        }).subscribe(({newData}) => {
            data = newData;
            this.serviceUpdated.emit();
        })
    }
```

So service is listening to signal "data-updated" from backend. If service recieves the one, it will ask backend to send updated data then save new data to itself.

```
export class MyComponent {
    data: string[] = [];
    
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        myService.serviceUpdated.subscribe((_) => { this.updateData(); });
    }

    public updateGens() {
       this.data = myService.data;
    }
```

So if service recieves signal, it calls method to update data. Component that subscribed on service's `serviceUpdated` will call updateData() too, but new data will not shown on frontend until I'll touch some button or do any other action with frontend.

I tried to call ChangeDetectorRef's detectChanges() every 50 millisecond in MyComponent's constructor, but this looks like cranch, bad code:

```
constructor(private genService: GenService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        genService.serviceUpdated.subscribe((_) => { this.updateGens(); });
        setInterval(() => { this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); }, 50);
}
```

Is there no better solution without calling detectChanges()?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `EventEmitter` try to use Subject instead and subscribe to it. Then instead of storing the data inside your service, just emit it directly using your subject

```
  export class MyService {
    public serviceUpdated$ = new Subject();

    public constructor() {
        this.updateService();
        listen('data-updated', () => { this.updateService(); })
    }

    private updateService() {
        forkJoin({
            // ask backend to send new data 
        }).subscribe(({newData}) => {
            this.serviceUpdated$.next(newData);
        })
    }
```

In your component, pass the new data to your `updateGens` function

```
export class MyComponent {
    data: string[] = [];
    
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        myService.serviceUpdated$.subscribe((data) => { this.updateData(data); });
    }

    public updateGens(data) {
       this.data = data;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sadly, but this doesn't help. Angular updates its view only after any user action, for example, pushing some button. Can virtual dom be the problem? I have hypothesis that components variables not mapped to real dom values directly -- angular updates them only in its lifetime cycles, so I need to trigger them somehow from backend. It could be ChangeDetectorRef::detectChanges() but it breaks other actions that can update view, such as opening some panels.